# Заблокировать gre протокол

Tags: linux, iptables, ddos

Ддосят `gre` протоколом(всеми версиями.)

Дамп: https://yadi.sk/i/aNWwyad1sCHRe

```
iptables -A INPUT -p 47 -j DROP
```

Так не блокируется, подскажите как правильно.

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "заблокировать" ? Пакеты если идут, то они все равно до вашей машины дойдут. и вы их даже tcpdump увидите. То что на input вы их порежете не позволит пакетам дойти до вашего pppd. Резать то надо на маршрутизаторе где то по дороге к вам, если совсем нигде их видеть не хотите

Comment: Канал у меня большой, но падает от этих баговых пакетов.
Так что нужно их дропать.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 3):

что бы вы с этими пакетами ни делали **на сервере**, они к вам всё равно будут **поступать**.

и будут забивать канал связи.

в такой ситуации «спасти» может лишь фильтрация подобных пакетов на **предшествующих** точках маршрутизации. например, у вашего сетевого провайдера.